# DigitalOcean Ubuntu droplet not serving port 80

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, server, port

I have a simple Python server on a DigitalOcean Ubuntu droplet that should serve the index.html file in the /dist folder:

```
port = 8000
os.chdir(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'dist'))
Handler = http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
httpd = socketserver.TCPServer(('', port), Handler)
print('Serving at port ', port)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

I ran 'sudo ufw allow 80/tcp' to open the firewall and if I run ufw status it shows port 80 as being open to everybody. I ran 'sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8000' to redirect traffic from port 80 to port 8000.

If I run nmap from another box, the only open port is ssh on 22. Port 80 is filtered. Navigating to the host in my browser results in a connection timeout. What could be causing this?

Comment: Have you checked the [cloud firewall](https://www.digitalocean.com/products/cloud-firewalls/)?

Comment: I never added one; on the DigitalOcean page it says 'You haven't applied any Firewalls to this Droplet yet.'

Comment: Does it work when you test it on the loopback interface (i.e. on the server itself)? Out of curiosity, why do you create a port forward instead of directly listening on port 80?

Comment: I tried doing it straight from port 80 and had the same result. If I try to run nmap or netstat from the server itself while it is running, port 80 shows open but the server crashes (connection reset by peer, no other useful error info).

Comment: This question might be a better fit for https://serverfault.com/ then.

Comment: I will try that, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I had to enable the DigitalOcean firewall and apply the correct rules, otherwise without the firewall it was just blocking ports by default.